# Is it possible to use mysql function in LIKE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I just wanted to know is it possible to use mysql function in where like clause.
I know function can be used in where = clause.

Example

I want to use this statement using  like clause

```
select year from t where year=year(now) -- possible

select year from t where year like 'year(now)'  --- is there any way to use function in like clause using quotes
```

Is it possible?

Comment: This seems fine to me...  Have you tried it?

Comment: i tried it was giving error but now figured it out as i missed now() in it thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's possible. But I'd avoid doing that because, depending on the function, it could affect performance.